# issue with updating record in database using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have object in database with values as follows:

- id =1
- name = "john"
- chargeid = 6

I am using merge statement to update the code
`em.merge(obj)`

**When i see the query generated by JPA i found that  in update query only fields which has new or not null values are updated.**

I checked the bean which is associated with this object and found that there is no annotations associated with chargid

Now when i try to update this JPA, it gets properly updated if i don't set anyvalue to null.
Now if i set chargeid= null and then try to set persist it into db, it doeskin get changed to null in db but it retails the previous value.How come?

The following are the details
1 have record in database as follows

```
ID     Name   chargeID
1     john      5
```

Now if i set values of objects as

```
obj.setID(1),
obj.setName("johnNew")
obj.setchargID(6)
entinymanager.merge(obj)
```

then record is updated as follows, which is fine

```
Id  name      chargeid
1    johnNew   6
```

Now if i want to set chargeid to null i use code

```
obj.setId(1)
obj.setName('XYZ')
obj.setChargeId(null); // i want to update it as null.
```

Now the record will be updated as follows

```
id  name  chargeid
1   XYZ    6        //name is updated to XYZ,but chargeid is not updated to null, how come?


i want to set chargeid to null.
```

Comment: @akp Post how do you perform this scenario (plain code), please

Comment: @arthur:thanks for replying.I use merge statement to update the record

Comment: Show some (pseudo) code to explain, I don't understand the description of the problem.

Comment: @pascal:I have updated the main post ,

Comment: Ok, now at least I understand the scenario. But the behavior is surprising. Can you activate SQL logging and check the generated SQL (and post it)?

Comment: i checked the generated SQL, i fond that in update statement chargid field is no set to null, chargeid is not updated in that query

Comment: @akp Weird. Please show the annotated entity.

Comment: @paskal.Sorry its my company code, i am not allowed to post it outside company.

Comment: I have checked  that annotated entity and there is no annotions for chargeid;

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for you because without code to reproduce, it will be hard to get an answer. Personally, I don't see why the field is not included in the update when null. This is an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, because I created a new object:

```
DatabaseObject obj = new DatabaseObject();
obj.setSomeValue(null);
obj.setRowId(1);
entityManager.merge(obj);
```

I thought if I explicitly set the id number that it wouldn't matter if the JPA object is new, or the existing one with the desired id. Perhaps you did the same?

The correct code is:

```
DatabaseObject obj = entityManager.find(DatabaseObject.class, (long) 1);
obj.setSomeValue(null);
obj.setRowId(1);
entityManager.merge(obj);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you do a `.find` first, then any changes you make to that object are updated when you `.merge`. If you create a new object and try to merge it, then the entityManager presumes that you just forgot to fill the field in and doesn't merge the null values

Answer (score 1):

Another option to do that is set the object as NULL after the merge method execution like below:

```
obj.setchargID(6)
obj = entinymanager.merge(obj)
obj.setchargID(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have an 'not null' defined for the chargeid column? (In your database)

Comment: i checked the  bean, it doesnnot have not null defined.And am notgeting any error.only chargeId field is not updated to null, it retains previous value

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below.
values which are not set explicitly will set to null automatically.

```
obj.setId(1);
obj.setName('XYZ');
entinymanager.merge(obj);
```

it will work..