# setting values of some fields to null using JPA

Tags: jpa, merge

In jpa merge, are all coumns updated or only the columns which have new values?

While updating if i set value of some attribute to null, will null value will be stored in that cloumn in db, or will it retain previous value?

Comment: This highly relates to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869543/issue-with-updating-record-in-database-using-jpa/

Answer (score 4):

When merging an entity X, the **whole state** of X will be "merged" (if X is a valid "candidate" of course). The JPA 1.0 specification puts it like this:

> #### 3.2.4.1 Merging Detached Entity State
>
> The merge operation allows for the
>   propagation of state from detached
>   entities onto persistent entities
>   managed by the EntityManager.
>
> The semantics of the merge operation
>   applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, **the state of X is copied** onto a pre-existing
>     managed entity instance X' of the same
>     identity or a new managed copy X' of X
>     is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created
>     and the state of X is copied into the
>     new managed entity instance X'.
> - If X is a removed entity instance, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>     thrown by the merge operation (or the
>     transaction commit will fail).
> - If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>     however, the merge operation is
>     cascaded to entities referenced by
>     relationships from X if these
>     relationships have been annotated with
>     the cascade element value
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`
>     annotation.
> - For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the
>     cascade element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>     `cascade=ALL`, Y is merged recursively
>     as Y'. For all such Y referenced by
>     X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note
>     that if X is managed then X is the
>     same object as X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL` is
>     not specified, then navigation of the
>     same association from X' yields a
>     reference to a managed object Y' with
>     the same persistent identity as Y.
>
> The persistence provider must not
>   merge fields marked LAZY that have not
>   been fetched: it must ignore such
>   fields when merging.
>
> Any `Version` columns used by the
>   entity must be checked by the
>   persistence runtime implementation
>   during the merge operation and/or at
>   flush or commit time. In the absence
>   of `Version` columns there is no
>   additional version checking done by
>   the persistence provider runtime
>   during the merge operation.