# EntityManager merge function setting non-set values of the obect to null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

em.merge() updating uninitialized properties of the entity to null..

```
@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager em;

    em.merge(invoice);
```

in my database it is updating all the values which were set in invoice object, 
as well as it is updating others to null as in invoice object those values were null.

what is the alternative of it so that i will update the object set values only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting values of some fields to null using JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870248/setting-values-of-some-fields-to-null-using-jpa)

Comment: The object is in what state when passed to merge? What state are the "other" fields ? loaded before detach? unloaded? Some implementations keep track of what is loaded at detach, but maybe your implementation doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Merge works by first selecting from your DB the entity u are going to merge (in this case invoice) and will check every field for changes. If they are now null they will be set to null.

One way to fix this is to either pass around the full entity or manualy select and set the only the fields u want modified.

Comment: thanks Cremson, i fetched entity from DB and then setting values which i want to set..now it is working..